# Cannot launch lxc containers get 'error: a remote name must be provided'

Tags: lxc

I'm trying to start using lxd/lxc containers using the series of blog posts from Stephane Graber: https://www.stgraber.org/2016/03/19/lxd-2-0-your-first-lxd-container-312/

The problem is that no matter what I do I can't get a container to launch using one of the default image repositories. For example this is based on one of hte examples in Stephane's blog post:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 c1
error: A remote name must be provided
```

I've tried all sorts of variations of the command but no luck. Can anyone point out what I've missed?

Comment: Found the solution is to prefix 'local:' for all local resources (images, containers etc.)

Answer (score 2):

In the version of lxd/lxc that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 you need to prefix `local:` for all resource names that are on the local LXD server. So the correct command becomes:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 local:c1
```

In an ideal world, all the blog posts from Stephane and others, which constitute the best documentation for lxd/lxc, would be edited to include this.